# How do I tell a windows batch script to execute the next line without waiting for the previous line to finish executing?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm setting up a .cmd script to be run on startup for a pseudo-server (It's actually a laptop, but that's irrelevant) to automatically launch pageant, load an SSH key, connect to an SSH server using Putty (Pageant would automatically authenticate with the key), then launch mIRC which in turn has a series of scripts setup to operate as an IRC bot and automatically connect to networks using putty as an SSH tunnel.

With that in mind, I have the below code in a startup.cmd file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" c:\Path\To\Private\Key.ppk
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh user@host
"C:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\mirc.exe"

EXIT
```

When I test run this file, the command prompt runs the first line, launches pageant, and then sits there and does nothing until I close pageant completely. I believe I have an idea on what the issue here is, but I can't find any information on how to resolve this in a batch file.

I do know on linux systems, if I were running a bash script to do something similar, I would want to have a & symbol at the end of each line to tell it to run the next command without waiting for the previous command to finish executing. I did try that in the batch script in the off chance that would work (It didn't).

For those who may ask, this is on Windows 8.1 64 bit. The user running this script is not an administrator.

Comment: `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pageant.exe" c:\Path\To\Private\Key.ppk`

Comment: The ampersand in bash is not telling it to not wait. It tells bash to launch the cmd in separate process in the background.

Comment: @Squashman - Your suggestion worked, using 'START' to run each program. The explanation of how the ampersand works makes more sense than how it was explained to me, too. Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you can put that into an answer (With explanation for anyone else who comes across this thread) I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This question probably gets asked so frequently we could probably just delete your question.  It is probably in the top 5 questions asked right along with delayed variable expansion.

Comment: Really? alright then. For the life of me I couldn't find an answer to this when I was searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment to expand on Squashman's suggestion, so let me answer here.

In your case, if you only want to have Pageant running in the background, without interacting with it, I think it's best to run:

```
START "" /B <your command>
```

The /B parameter will spawn the process without launching a new window for it, which seems like something you'd like to avoid (anyway, it's probably closest to the behaviour you can obtain in Linux with &).

Please note that if you close the window from which you spawned this process, it will terminate as well.

Comment: Specifically, for Pageant, it already runs without opening a window when started through the command line like this - It minimizes to the task tray on startup.

I'm assuming the last sentence means if I use 'EXIT' in the bash script or close command prompt, it would close anything opened with /B

Comment: Basically went with this, minus the /B parameter.

Comment: Oh, thanks for telling me! I don't use Pageant personally, so I didn't know it doesn't launch a separate window by default, but it's good to know just in case. :) And the /B option is worth remembering anyway, I think.

Comment: And yes, my last sentence meant exactly that. Sorry for not making it completely clear.